# My custom module is not installing on the odoo platform

Tags: python, odoo

I created a custom module, changed the addons path in the `odoo.conf` so my app reflects on the app list successfully.
The problem I am having is, the app throws an error when I try to install it:

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1331, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1319, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-59>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 72, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 463, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 573, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 423, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 315, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\module.py", line 376, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 13.0\server\addons\my_todo\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import todo_task_model
ImportError: cannot import name 'todo_task_model' from 'odoo.addons.my_todo' (c:\program files (x86)\odoo 13.0\server\addons\my_todo\__init__.py)
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: Did you create `todo_task_model` file or folder  inside `my_todo` folder?

Answer (score 0):

For this error @lyke, maybe you didn't put 'from . import models' in your Init file. Try to verify this.